# Running a python script in another PC

Tags: python

I have to check versions of different software and their proper patches and I have written a python script that works `(developed in my office laptop)`.

Now I have to run the scripts in my labs and the lab PCs do not have python and I am not allowed to install python on them.

Is there a way to run my python script in the labs?

Options I have seen

1. Convert my python to an EXE and run it.

   - If I choose this option, I do not prefer the use of the scheduler to run the EXE in a fixed time as the labs may be used for testing.
   - How do I create API for my code so I can call the API and run it as needed?
   - or is there a better way than I have missed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Comment: Yes , this is similar to my requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use this alternative way if you dont want to compile to EXE:

**For Running Script**

1. Download Portable Python in Folder [here](https://portablepython.com/wiki/Download/)
2. (Optional for additional packeges used) Place venv(Python Virtual Enviroment) in same folder
3. (Optional) Use venv with `python.exe -m venv env`
4. Open cmd in folder with `python.exe`
5. Run your script with `python.exe script.py`

**For API:**

You can use arguments for API ,it depends how much time and effort you want to put in.

1. **Use sys.args and run script with required arguments**
2. Use TCP Server on allowed ports and listen for commands* (Can be time consuming if you didnt worked with TCP)*